# I am getting a CSV file genereated from datamapper. But the values are written into the file within double quotes. How to overcome this issue

Tags: csv, mule, export-to-csv, datamapper, mule-studio

The output of my datamapper is a csv file. And the output looks like the below one.

For eg:

```
     "1","10"
     "3","40"
```

But my requirement"

```
      1,10
      3,40
```

What configuration should i do to get the o/p as required. Pls suggest!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Click on the options circled in red on the destination profile and uncheck the check box "Quote Strings" in the pop up that comes there after .

[image]

Some times the CSV file has this Quotes by default

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the info.  

What if instead of a delimiter ','  I need to include some spaces between the values.
For eg:

        1           10(newline)


        3          40(newline)

Comment: In the answer above you can see a "+" symbol next to the drop down. Can you try clicking that and give a space as the delimiter. In that location you can give your custom delimiter. Try it and let me know

Comment: No that is not working. 
It is showing an invalid delimiter error. Could you help me with an alternative!!

Comment: Can you try "&nbsp;" or "%20" instead of space ?

Comment: no luck.. it didnt work. any alternatives..

Also any suggestions for this question
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32264731/splitting-an-xml-message-and-aggregating-based-on-some-condition-in-mule-esb